# Excel How can I paste automatically a value into its related cell on a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list of **cities** `column A` and the **tourism data** `columns B` ordered on an Excel row by a personal criteria (facebook campaigns).

Every week I would like to paste the *new* tourism data of each city into `column C`, `column D`, etc...

But the list I can extract is ordered alphabetically, not by my personal criteria.

Could it be possible to paste the new values of `column C` ordered by the cities I have in `Column A`?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Show some example of your Data your list and the extracted

Answer (score 0):

You need a column for the cities at the left of the new tourism and use the following formula:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$G$2:$H$7,2,FALSE),"")`

Iferror if no cities
Vlookup with False to find the exact match
2 for the second column (new tourism)
$G$2:$H$7 the new data with Cities in column G
And New Tourism in column H
A2 is the first city in the order and listed column

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***Caveat:*** This assumes that your data is numeric. In the future, please give data examples.

Change how you store it to a four column listing like this:

[image]

I know that's less useful to look at, but we'll address that separately.

Then, to make it easier on yourself later, highlight the entire rectangle of cells *including the header row* and choose Insert Table and click Insert - Table.

[image]

This table now has a name. I'm just going to pretend it's "Table1" but you can view and change it if you put your cursor into the table so that the context-sensitive "Table Tools - Design" ribbon appears, then click the ribbon. The first choice on that ribbon will allow you to change the table name.

Now, insert a pivot table that uses "Table1" with Campaign and Cities values in the "Row Labels" section, Weeks in the "Column Labels" section, and Data in the "Values" section. (The image below was created on a new tab.)

[image]

Once you do this you can append/insert data into the table in whatever order you get it, then refresh the pivot table and see it organized however you like, add row totals as well, automatically format your data, and play with the data more easily. For example, you move the Campaigns into the Column Headers and move the weeks to the row labels, drag "Data" into the data section again and then customize it to show percentage of parent subtotals, change the titles of the fields, add conditional formatting to highlight the % per campaign with the highest subtotal, go into the "PivotTable Tools\Design" ribbon and change the style, etc.

[image]
*(the values here are different because I was playing with them, but the format of the data table the pivot table didn't change)*